# least square in muliple regressions

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to understand the impact of changes in the features to the least-square estimated coefficients. Can somebody provide some insight on this question?

> If you double the value of a given feature (i.e. a specific column of the feature matrix), what happens to the least-squares estimated coefficients for every other feature? (assume you have no other feature that depends on the doubled feature i.e. no interaction terms).

Comment: Is this a homework question?  If so, please add the self-study tag.

Comment: Instead of indenting your actual question by 4 spaces, just use the `>` sign, then it will look like a quote.

Comment: Are you using some sort of statistical software in your analysis?  If so, have  you tried using your data (or any fake dataset) and carrying out a test by doubling one of the x-values?  What happens to the coefficients when you do so?  I would repeat this with a few different dataset to see if the results of your experiment are the same.

Comment: they stay the same.

Comment: Doubling all the values doesn't change anything about what your data *represent*, because it merely is a change of units of measurement.  For instance, if the feature represents the amount of an ingredient in a recipe given in ounces and you decide instead to express it in tablespoons, you will double all the values. Do you think that should change the model in any way?

Comment: Please show a small example where you estimated the regression and then doubled all the values for one of the x-columns and re-estimated, but (as you claim in your comment) the coefficient stayed the same. I'd live to see what you did.

Comment: Maybe he doubled **everything**, including $Y$!

Answer (score 1):

If the respective feature is independent with other features, doubling it wont change the least-squares estimated coefficients for every other feature. It will still find the optimal parameters for other features